# Please explain to me how does the result get to 15?, with this example of C# While Loop

Tags: c#, while-loop

Could someone please explain to me how I get to the result of 15, with this example of C# While Loop:

```
int result = 0;
int x = 6;

while (x > 3)
{
   result = result + x;
   x = x - 1;
}
```

Comment: You should get an overflow exception, or 0, depending on the value of X (big X, not small x - I can't see where big X is defined)

Comment: inside your while loop use if (result==15) break; With more practice you will have good skills.

Comment: Debugger is the best friend. Learn to use it.

Comment: @John - big X was a typo error. I stand corrected, i meant small x

Comment: x = 6, result + 6 = 6. x = 5, result + 5 = 11, x = 4, result + 4 = 15, x = 3, x is not > 3, so the loop exits.

Comment: Thanks all, for the comments. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is effectively performing the calculation 0 + 6 + 5 + 4 = 15.

result is initialised to 0, then the while loop will perform 3 iterations, adding 6, then 5 then 4 to result, as x is decreased by 1 each time.

When x is decreased to 3 on the 3rd iteration, the while loop will exit and no further additions will take place.

Comment: @Jonathan: I now understand the calculation part, with just one exception though. When: result + 4=15, shouldn't 15 now become 14 with the subtraction of: x = x - 1 ?

Comment: No, that is subtracting 1 from x; result is unaffected by that.